# Windows Script to copy or update a jar file is not working

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have prepared the below script to copy "sigma 1.jar file from source to destination. But the entire folder is getting copied instead of just the sigma 1.jar file. All I want is that jar file to be copied to destination. Nothing else should be copied.

I have tried the /E option & getting the same result.

Below is the script

```
@mkdir Z:\backup20160812
@xcopy "Z:\Testing\A 1\Sigma 1.jar" "Z:\backup20160812\A 1\Sigma 1.jar" /H
@echo -------backup successfully!-------
@pause
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that explains the specific problem you're having. Seeing *What is wrong with my WIndows script?* in a set of search results will be totally meaningless to future users here.

Comment: You could execute `pushd "Z:\Testing\A 1"` before the `xcopy` line and `popd` afterwards; the `xcopy` line needs to be changed to `@xcopy /H "Sigma 1.jar" "Z:\backup20160812\A 1\Sigma 1.jar"` then; by the way, why are you using `xcopy` rather than `copy` to copy a single file? I recommend the latter as `xcopy` might prompt you for the target to be a file or directory, while `copy` won't...

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I have tried with copy as well and it is throwing an error "The system cannot find the file specified"

Answer (score -2):

Rename the files and folders so there are no spaces (ex: A1 instead of A 1)
then try

```
    @mkdir Z:\backup20160812
    @xcopy "Z:\Testing\A1\Sigma1.jar" "Z:\backup20160812\A1\Sigma1.jar" /H
    @echo -------backup successfully!-------
    @pause
```

Comment: The paths are enclosed in double-quotes, so this answer is useless.